# Swift 5 track CLLocation current position dot

Tags: swift, location, cllocationmanager, gmsmapview

i want draw circle around current position dot and move it with that dot. I did GMSCircle and i set to newCoordinates which i got from **didUpdateLocations**. But "dot coordinates" and actual coordinates from **didUpdateLocations** are different (look screenshot)

**GMSCircle**

```
lazy var circle: GMSCircle = {
    let circle = GMSCircle()

    circle.fillColor = PineappleColors.green.color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    circle.strokeWidth = 0
    circle.strokeColor = PineappleColors.green.color

    return circle
}()
```

**Set circle**

```
func setCircle(_ loc: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    UI.circle.position = loc
    UI.circle.map = UI.map
}
```

**didUpdateLocations**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location = locations.first else {
        return
    }
    let newLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!
    UI.map.clear()
    setCircle(newLoc)
    disableLocationManager()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it because of the camera position? Can you set it to 0 and test?

Comment: @satheeshwaran its the same.. i need to pin it to that dot... but i don't know if possible to take her position

Comment: What are you doing in disablocationManager method? Try removing that call and let location keep updating for a while.

Comment: @satheeshwaran disableLocationManager is  .stopUpdatindLocation() and .delegate = nil

Comment: I suppose that might be a problem, can you try without calling that method and see if the circle is drawn correctly?